# How to type a Form component with onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I've got my own `Form` component which I want to keep separated from the `Parent Component`.

```
const Form: React.FC<any> = ({ children, handleFormSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>{children}</form>
);
```

`Parent Component`

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
...

const handleFormSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    publishReview(review).then(() => setReview(initialReviewState));
  };

return (
 <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
...
</Form>
)}
```

I thought `handleFormSubmit` would get the types from its declaration `const handleFormSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)`.

But it doesn't

I've tried to build an interface and even with an `any` type:

```
interface FormProps {
  handleFormSubmit: any
}
const Form: React.FC<FormProps>= ({ children, handleFormSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>{children}</form>
);
```

But it gave the below error:

```
const Form: React.FunctionComponent<FormProps>
Type '{ children: Element; onSubmit: (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FormProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Answer (score 84):

This worked for me.  Just guessing based on your guess.  Thanks!

```
handlePostForm = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is. It's not letting you destruct the props from `e.target`

Comment: You'd know better that I, I just happened to have read this in a book and answered based on that. But in the end I don't think the author really was all that good at it because the example strategies left real issues in functionality.

Answer (score 24):

You would need to specify the type of the form elements. Let's say for example in your form you have an input with id `yourInputName`:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="yourInputName">Username:</label>
    <input id="yourInputName" type="text" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your `handleSubmit`, you would need to specify the type of the `event.currentTarget`. A form tag has a type of `HTMLFormElement` with a property `elements`, which are a type of `HTMLFormControlsCollection`, but we can override that to tell TS what our input is. Create an interface which extends the `HTMLFormControlsCollection`, specify the type of your field and then use the custom interface to override the elements property in the `HTMLFormElement`.

```
interface FormElements extends HTMLFormControlsCollection {
    yourInputName: HTMLInputElement
}

interface YourFormElement extends HTMLFormElement {
   readonly elements: FormElements
}
```

Then you pass that new type to your handling function

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<YourFormElement>) => {}
```

You can now access the value of your field and typescript will know what it is

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<YourFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.currentTarget.elements.yourInputName.value)
}
```

If you hover on `value`, TS should show you a message that the data type is `HTMLInputElement.value: string`, just as you have specified in your `FormElements` interface.

Answer (score 14):

```
  const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have uncontrolled form in react( i used MUI field) :

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            error={isError}
            helperText={isError ? 'Incorrect entry.' : ''}
            margin="normal"
            color="success"
            label="Name and surname"
            id="nameSurname"
            size="small"
          /></form>
```

you can make this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
e.preventDefault();
const target = e.target as typeof e.target & {
  nameSurname: { value: string };
  //password: { value: string };
};
const nameSurname = target.nameSurname.value;
console.log(`nameSurname`, nameSurname);
```

};
inspired from [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/)

Answer (score 2):

As Ivo wrote, but in case you want to properly type it with `type`:

```
type FormElements = Readonly<
  {
    yourInputName: HTMLInputElement
  } & HTMLFormControlsCollection
>;

type YourFormElement = Readonly<
  {
    elements: FormElements;
  } & HTMLFormElement
>;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers here are just copying what OP had in the question, ie. `React.FormEvent`

That type is useless, because you cannot ensure type safety on the `currentTarget`

### Most concise way of typing FormEvent `currentTarget`

```
import { FormEventHandler } from 'react'

interface ExampleForm extends HTMLFormElement {
  someValue: HTMLInputElement;
}

const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<ExampleForm> = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault() // stop refresh
 const { someValue } = e.currentTarget // properly typed
 console.log(someValue.value); // contains the value of your input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a mistake in your prop names.  Do you see the mismatch?

```
const Form: React.FC<any> = ({ children, handleFormSubmit }) => (
```

```
<Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
```

**Your `Form` component takes a prop named `handleFormSubmit`, but you are calling it with a prop named `onSubmit` instead.**

You need to change the name in one of those places so that they both match.  Either call `<Form handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>` or change the props of the `Form` component so that the prop is named `onSubmit`.

---

Here's how it should look if you rename the prop to `onSubmit` and give it a proper type instead of `any`.

```
interface FormProps {
    onSubmit: React.FormEventHandler;
}

const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = ({ children, onSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>{children}</form>
);
```

You do not need to make any changes in your `ParentComponent` if you define `Form` like this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/category", { name });
      if (data?.error) {
        toast.error(data.error);
      } else {
        setName("");
        toast.success(`"${data.name}" is created`);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      toast.error("Create category failed. Try again.");
    }
  };
```